# How to implement a very efficient Queue in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, queue

I have an event-handler that performs some bulky task every time some event occurs. Now these events occurs rapidly and the bulkiness of the handler causes it to lag or miss some of these events.

I want the event-handler to enqueue the event details in a queue and delegate the bulky part of the task to another asynchronous function, like the `setInterval(handler2, time-interval)`. The `handler2` will dequeue the events and perform the bulky tasks.

I want to know about how to create a queue. I have seen other answers and they use `shift()` operation on the a `list` which run in `O(n)` time.

Assume I am a beginner in JS.

Comment: It would help, if you'd describe the the events more precisely. A common bulk events are ex. mousemove, resize and key events, are the events some of these, or are you polling data from a server? If the latter, how much data is involved per an event? Where/how is the results of the bulky part used, is it a DOM manipulation, just storing some data etc ..?  `setInterval` is not creating another thread to run its callback, and the total execution will take as much time as running the bulky part in the event handler itself. Maybe you could benefit from WebWorkers?

Comment: I have several mousemove event listener. A user would move their mouse over thousands of such elements. Everytime an event is fired a handler would do some calculations based on current and previous position of the mouse. It is okay if setInterval is not asynchronous. I just need it to regularly consume the queue elements and perform those calculations, the queue will be filled by event-handler. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: The previous example I linked was a bit costy, here's a fixed [example](https://jsfiddle.net/brqdo6v3/).

Comment: Very nice. btw can we make a shift operation O(1) time. The shift is O(n) because every time it pop an element from the top, it then performs indexing to get the length of the list, causing linear running time. I do not want it to do the indexing, rather I want to do the head and tail pointer comparison to avoid underflow, like we do in C language. Is it possible? I am a quite beginner in JS, my life would have been simpler if we had pointers and structure like in C. but thanks for attending my question.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, you can use `pop` to pull the last element out from the array. Or keep book of the index, and just read a value without mutating the array at all.